# Casperjs Multiple Test Cases

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have written webui automated testing cases of a webUI using Casperjs.
it includes:

1. home.js (checks home page in log-in state)
2. premium.js (checks premium user in log-in state)
3. catagories.js (checks categories page in log-in state)
4. Favorite.js (checks favorite page in log-in state)

I can run these tests successfully. 
**Is there a way to run them all at once? So that I can test all the pages at once when I want?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by creating a single script and create different functions to test each of the functionalities. The following code may give some idea

```
casper.start();
var running = 1; 
var home_js = function(){
  //your casper steps in home.js
};
var premium_js = function(){
  // your steps in premium.js
  // at end set running = 0 to stop the execution
};
var controller = function(){
  if(running==1){
   home_js.call(this);
   premium_js.call(this);
   casper.run(controller);
  }else{
    this.exit();
  }
}
casper.run(controller);
```